# Need to connect Azure infrastructure from AWS Devops services. Is this really possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, devops, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

All my infrastructure is on AWS since long time and we are using all Devops services of AWS like code commit, code pipeline, Now there is a new requirement to push one of the web application to Azure cloud platform.

Is it really possible to connect from AWS Devops tools to Azure to create,deploy and maintain updates on web application. Basically CICD process on Azure connecting from AWS services.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Azure CLI to manage your Azure pipeline on AWS side but this is not a good pattern.

Another way is to create a pipeline using Azure DevOps Tools and trigger this pipeline using AWS.